# How do you copy data from current page1.html to window.open('page2.html')

Tags: javascript, html

When pressing a button on page1.html I want to open page2.html in new window and copy some data from page1.html to page2.html.

I tried running open_copy() on page1.html

```
<button id="manual" onclick="open_copy()" type="button" class="btn-primary">copy age</button>

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
```

I try using local storage, it works but it isn't nice...

```
 function open_copy()
{
  var age=document.getElementById('age').value;
  var n= window.open('page2.html');
  n.focus();  
  n.document.getElementById('age').value=0.0001;
}
```

I want to copy age data from page1 to page2.html

Comment: You'll want to either `POST` the data from page 1 to page 2 using AJAX, or make use or `localStorage` / `sessionStorage`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Comment: you can set value in url (get method) , page2.html?value=22

Comment: I already use local storage but not sure it is good for all browsers...
How do you load the POST/GET value into page2.html ?
I want to load it into document.getElementById('age').value of page2

Comment: pretty sure [it works in every browser that has JS capability](https://caniuse.com/#search=localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

In your page1, set the data you want to pass to a local storage like this

```
var age=document.getElementById('age').value;
localStorage.setItem('age', age);
```

then in your page2, get your data from the local storage like this

```
var age = localStorage.getItem('age');
```

**SYNTAX**

To Set

`localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')`

To get

`localStorage.getItem('key')`

Comment: Thanks Jk,
I use to activate localStorage.getItem('key') on the onload of pag2.html.
Is there a way to do it from page1.html, on open_copy() ?

also do you knoe how to use the POST  option?

Comment: There's no way to do that on page1. localstorage is useless if you can load the data from page1 to page2 in the first place. I do know how to use POST option but I suggest you stick to localstorage. Post option is 10x more complicated than localstorage. You'll need to create API and database for that.